# CMake undefined reference to class

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to compile a project using CMake, but I'm getting undefined references to class functions that I have created. If I create a Makefile by hand, everything compiles fine. But when I use CMake, I'm getting `undefined reference` errors.

This is the directory structure:

`.
    ├── build
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── info
    │   ├── indexer.pdf
    │   └── search.pdf
    ├── Makefile
    ├── sample
    │   ├── 1
    │   │   └── b.txt
    │   ├── 2
    │   │   └── c.txt
    │   ├── 3
    │   │   └── d.txt
    │   └── a.txt
    ├── src
    │   ├── cpp
    │   │   ├── index.cpp
    │   │   └── record.cpp
    │   ├── h
    │   │   ├── index.h
    │   │   └── record.h
    │   └── main.cpp
    ├── tests
    │   └── a
    └── todo.txt`

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# Project Name
PROJECT(indexer CXX)

# Binary dir
# Built in CMake variables:
    # CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR: the directory where cmake was executed
    # CMAKE_BINARY_DIR: where the output will go 
    # EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH: common place to put executables if         you don't want it to be CMAKE_BINARY_DIR
    # LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH: common place to put libraries if you don't want it to be CMAKE_BINARY_DIR

set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

# Add additional compiler flags
# Built-ins:
#   - CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = -g
#   - CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE = -O3 -NDEBUG
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x -Wall")


include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/h")

# Aggregate the sources
file(GLOB SOURCES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/cpp")

add_executable(indexer "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp" ${SOURCES})``
```

Error:

```
CMakeFiles/indexer.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `parse(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Index*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1b5): undefined reference to `Record::Record(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1ee): undefined reference to `Index::add(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Record)'
CMakeFiles/indexer.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x77d): undefined reference to `Index::Index()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x84b): undefined reference to `Index::print()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/indexer.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'indexer' failed
make[2]: *** [indexer] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/indexer.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/indexer.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I suggest you check the value of `${SOURCES}`, it's probably not what you expect it to be. I also suggest you read a little bit more about [the `file` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) and what the `GLOB` option really does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with the line

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/cpp")
```

This will set the `SOURCES` variable to a file named `cpp` in the `src` directory. I think you meant something like

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/cpp/*.cpp")
```

This will catch all files that end with the extension `.cpp`, and put them into the `SOURCES` variable.

Note: I don't think you will need to pass `"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp"` as an argument to `create_executable`, since your `SOURCES` variable should already contain the `main.cpp`.

Comment: Yes, this is what it was. What I should have done was ``src/cpp/*.cpp`` so that it would catch all the files. Thank you!